# Get max values of column inside Group By where value is not null

Tags: mysql

I have one table with two columns like:

```
Patient_Letter_id, Version
1                    1
1                    2
NULL                  1
NULL                  1
2                     1
2                     2
2                     3
```

Now I want query to get Max value of Version record of same patient_letter_id, if patient_letter_id is null then return that rows like below:

```
patient_letter_id   Version
1                     2
NULL                  1
NULL                  1
2                     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Group By function and then Union with records has null values.
You might try this:

```
select patient_letter_id,version
from yourtable
where version is null
union
select patient_letter_id,max(version) as version
from yourtable
where version is not null
group by patient_letter_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select patient_letter_id, max(version) as version
from testing
group by case 
         when patient_letter_id is null then rand() 
         else patient_letter_id
         end
```